# Servlet is not applying changes

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

After first compilation of my Servlet, every next modification in code is not visible by server. I get exacly same output no matter what I write in class. I tried to re-configure Tomcat in Eclipse but that didin't work. Servlet contains connector to SQL and his job is to get data from table and send it to .jsp file via getRequestRispatcher and because I gave the method wrong jsp path it gives an exception that it can't find file. However, even when I change path to correct for Servlet is like nothing has changed and it still gives same exception.

Code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Load_table
 */
@WebServlet("/Load_table")
public class Load_table extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Load_table() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            List<Towar> magazyn = accessData();

            request.setAttribute("magazyn", magazyn);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/Main.jsp").include(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    public List<Towar> accessData() {

        List<Towar> output = new ArrayList<Towar>();

        final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";


       final String USER = "log";
        final String PASS = "pass";


       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{

          Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);


          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);



          System.out.println("Creating statement...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = String.format("SELECT * from Towary");
          PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

          ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery();


          while(rs.next()){



             output.add(new Towar(rs.getString("Nazwa"), rs.getString("Cena"),
                     rs.getString("Stan")));

          }


          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){

          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){

          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{

          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       return output;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you already check your code in debug mode? Can you post your code?

Comment: I am sure your project w.r.t tomcat in eclipse is not configured properly.just restart the server or re-deploy your project ,problem will get solve

Comment: @AbhishekMishra : Tried both, and still no effect

Comment: delete the content of temp and work folder inside tomcat and then try your luck

Comment: @RE350 : posted code

Comment: @AbhishekMishra : unfortunately problem still exist

Comment: That seems wired.. are you deploying your project through eclipse or directly in tomcat by add project inside  webapps folder

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the deployed apps from tomcat work directory then restart tomcat and deploy again.hope you will get latest changes.